# Populate a dataframe based on a aggregated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this which is generated after some aggregations and conditions,

```
X      P       D1           D2
1      A    2016-06-02   2016-07-26
2      A    2016-10-04   2016-12-01
3      A    2016-12-13   2017-03-11
1      B    2017-03-04   2018-01-11
```

From this dataframe, I have to populate another dataframe that has n number of columns where each column is for a month in the range of `[201606, 201607,......, 201801]` which is made earlier. ie I already have a dataframe with columns as mentioned above. I want to populate that dataframe.

I want to make a row for each record in the aggregated dataframe, where the combination of X, P will be unique throughout the aggregated dataframe.

For the first record, I want to fill the columns 201606 to 201607 ie from `D1` to `D2` (both inclusive) with 1. All other columns should be `0`

For the second row, I want to fill the columns 201610 to 201612 with `1` and `0` for every other column, and so on for every row in the aggregated dataframe.

How can I do this faster and efficiently using pandas? I prefer not to loop through the dataframe as my data will be huge.

If populating an existing dataframe is not ideal, generating a dataframe as I mentioned above can also serve my purpose.

Comment: Are you going to create this dataframe or populate an existing one ?
"From this dataframe, I have to populate **another dataframe** which have n number of columns where each column if for a month in the range of min(D1) to max(D2) ie like [201606, 201607,......, 201801]"

Comment: Actually, I want to populate. I will have a dataframe with columns like `[201606, ....., 201801]` with me already. I have edited the question to show this. If populating is an issue I can go with creating from the aggregated dataframe too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine how to not iterate anything. But it is possible to iterate either the rows of the initial dataframe or the columns of the resulting dataframe:

First build the resulting dataframe with all columns to 0

```
resul = pd.DataFrame(data = 0, columns=pd.period_range(df.D1.min(), df.D2.max(), freq='M'),
                     index = df.index)
```

1. Iterating rows of the initial dataframe:

   ```
   for ix, row in df.iterrows():
       resul.loc[ix, pd.period_range(row.D1, row.D2, freq='M')] = 1
   ```
2. Iterating columns of the result dataframe

   ```
   for c in resul.columns:
       resul[c] = np.where((c.end_time>=df.D1)&(c.start_time <= df.D2), 1, 0)
   ```

In both case, with your sample data it gives as expected:

```
   2016-06  2016-07  2016-08  2016-09  2016-10  2016-11  2016-12  2017-01  2017-02  2017-03  2017-04  2017-05  2017-06  2017-07  2017-08  2017-09  2017-10  2017-11  2017-12  2018-01
0        1        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
1        0        0        0        0        1        1        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        1        1        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
3        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

The choice between both methods will be the shorter iteration: if initial dataframe has less rows that the resul dataframe has columns, then choose method 1, else method 2

Comment: You solution looks cool. I had implemented something similar. Let me check my time constraints and get back to you.